# Laravel 5.7 Controller check which button has been clicked

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am current using laravel 5.7 I have a form in a bootstrap modal that has 2 tabs and each tab will display its submit button respectively. I am trying to **capture which submit button has been click** from my controller. I have already tried using `Input::get('btn-name');` and `$request->submit == 'btn-name'` but neither of the methods are working for me. I tried `dd(Input::all())` but it did not even capture the clicked button

**Update**

i have tried changing both my button name to `create-btn` and added these in my controller and it displays `"none"` in the `dd($action);`

```
$action = Input::get('create-btn','none');
if($action == 'create-team'){
    $project->type = 'Team';
    dd($action);
}else if($action == 'create-personal'){
    $project->type = 'personal';
    dd($action);
}else{
    dd($action);
}
```

**HTML**

The `<a>` tag is not inside the `<form>` tag is because it is located at the modal's footer hence i use an `on-event` function

```
<!--Team Tab Button-->
<button action="{{route('project.store')}}" 
    method="POST" 
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    name="create-btn" 
    value="create-team" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('submit-form 
    personal').submit();">Createdd changes
</button>`

<!--Personal Tab Button-->
<button action="{{route('project.store')}}" 
    method="POST" 
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    name="create-btn" 
    value="create-personal" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('submit-form- 
    personal').submit();">Createdd changes
</button>`
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'p_name' => 'required|min:6|max:50',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required',
    ]);

    $project = new Project;
    $project->p_name = $request->input('p_name');
    $project->start_date = $request->input('start_date');
    $project->end_date = $request->input('end_date');
    $project->colab = $request->input('colab');

   dd(Input::all()); 

    if($request->submit == 'create-team'){

        $project->type = 'team  ';
        $project->save();
    }


    return 123;
}
```

Comment: I think `action` and `method` are form attribute.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz no it is not if i take out `$project->save();` out from the `if` block it does save the values to my database

Comment: Anyone able to help? in desperate need of solution

Comment: Are you using 1 form to do this? What `<a>` tag are you talking about? There are plenty of ways to achieve this. A quick one i could suggest is to add a query parameter to the action url like: `action="{{route('project.store'). '?type=team'}}"` and `action="{{route('project.store'). '?type=personal'}}"` accordingly. Then in the controller check for the `Input::get('type')` field.